# ORDER BY NULL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

What is `ORDER BY NULL` in MySQL?

Does it decrease the query speed?

Comment: If you don't want to order by anything just omit the order by clause altogether

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's for performance; adding `ORDER BY NULL` after a `GROUP BY` clause will make your query faster.

An explanation, from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html):

> By default, MySQL sorts all `GROUP BY col1, col2, ...` queries as if you specified `ORDER BY col1, col2, ...` in the query as well. If you include an explicit `ORDER BY` clause that contains the same column list, MySQL optimizes it away without any speed penalty, although the sorting still occurs. If a query includes `GROUP BY` but you want to avoid the overhead of sorting the result, you can suppress sorting by specifying `ORDER BY NULL`. For example:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO foo
> SELECT a, COUNT(*) FROM bar GROUP BY a ORDER BY NULL;
> ```

[This article](http://www.subelsky.com/2008/05/order-by-null-kills-mysql-filesorts.html) describes the author successfully optimising a slow query by exploiting this trick, complete with the relevant parts of the `EXPLAIN` output.

Answer (score 12):

This link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Says it speeds up queries that use GROUP BY:

> If a query includes GROUP BY but you want to avoid the overhead of sorting the result, you can suppress sorting by specifying ORDER BY NULL.

Answer (score 8):

Since Mysql 8.0 ORDER BY NULL doesn't improve query performance.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

> Previously (MySQL 5.7 and lower), GROUP BY sorted implicitly under
>   certain conditions. In MySQL 8.0, that no longer occurs, so specifying
>   ORDER BY NULL at the end to suppress implicit sorting (as was done
>   previously) is no longer necessary. However, query results may differ
>   from previous MySQL versions. To produce a given sort order, provide
>   an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score -2):

Some developers used ORDER BY NULL to increase the speed of the queries using the GROUP BY clause.

The reason is that prior to MySQL 5.6 there was an implicit sort of the data when calling the GROUP BY clause. So adding ORDER BY NULL was inactivating this implicit sort and consequently making the query run faster.

Since MySQL 5.6, the implicit sorting of the GROUP BY clause is DEPRECATED http://www.tocker.ca/2013/10/21/heads-up-implicit-sorting-by-group-by-is-deprecated-in-mysql-5-6.html

Therefore the ORDER BY NULL technique is now useless.

Comment: [Official doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html) also says: "**Note** Relying on implicit `GROUP BY` sorting in MySQL 5.6 is deprecated."

Comment: -1; this answer is wrong. *Relying* on the implicit sorting is deprecated, but it is still part of MySQL and so ORDER BY NULL still serves a purpose. The very article that you link to even states that *nothing has changed yet*.

Answer (score -3):

I am soory but i can see perfomance :

```
mysql> SELECT *,COUNT(status) FROM big_table GROUP BY status;
+----------------+----------------------------------+--------+---------------+
| id             | hash                             | status | COUNT(status) |
+----------------+----------------------------------+--------+---------------+
| 14149924276950 | 20e2873f1026c867a1044681895130b8 |      0 |        268044 |
| 14149924273884 | 889dc604799c563783396a3cb2c688a5 |      1 |        277474 |
|  1414992427397 | 4e1769e2e64e737f37b918b834f8f696 |      2 |        279815 |
| 14149924277490 | 539b71f083fc95a93d0d4b904a56ebb2 |      3 |        290216 |
| 14149924274097 | ec694b8fc1786ea4f612dbe55d351715 |      4 |        272748 |
| 14149924272735 | 64c3d1077c3ed3ee02398896376327aa |      5 |        280785 |
| 14149924278670 | 05c143790ba4ecf73fc3be78d095c067 |      6 |        295417 |
| 14149924271189 | 79bcafe38074703a49fb372c95e3676a |      7 |        310937 |
| 14149924273279 | 29069b0fe511c160e95f98e2e2b770ac |      8 |        279338 |
| 14149924277367 | 2e72091679aa6e3d64ed3c407ceeb6d4 |      9 |        281226 |
+----------------+----------------------------------+--------+---------------+
10 rows in set (44.43 sec)

mysql> SELECT *,COUNT(status) FROM big_table GROUP BY status ORDER BY NULL;
+----------------+----------------------------------+--------+---------------+
| id             | hash                             | status | COUNT(status) |
+----------------+----------------------------------+--------+---------------+
| 14149924272735 | 64c3d1077c3ed3ee02398896376327aa |      5 |        280785 |
| 14149924277367 | 2e72091679aa6e3d64ed3c407ceeb6d4 |      9 |        281226 |
|  1414992427397 | 4e1769e2e64e737f37b918b834f8f696 |      2 |        279815 |
| 14149924278670 | 05c143790ba4ecf73fc3be78d095c067 |      6 |        295417 |
| 14149924274097 | ec694b8fc1786ea4f612dbe55d351715 |      4 |        272748 |
| 14149924271189 | 79bcafe38074703a49fb372c95e3676a |      7 |        310937 |
| 14149924276950 | 20e2873f1026c867a1044681895130b8 |      0 |        268044 |
| 14149924273279 | 29069b0fe511c160e95f98e2e2b770ac |      8 |        279338 |
| 14149924277490 | 539b71f083fc95a93d0d4b904a56ebb2 |      3 |        290216 |
| 14149924273884 | 889dc604799c563783396a3cb2c688a5 |      1 |        277474 |
+----------------+----------------------------------+--------+---------------+
10 rows in set (44.13 sec)
```

Comment: By default, MySQL sorts all GROUP BY col1, col2, ... queries as if you specified ORDER BY col1, col2, ... in the query as well. If you include an explicit ORDER BY clause that contains the same column list, MySQL optimizes it away without any speed penalty, although the sorting still occurs. If a query includes GROUP BY but you want to avoid the overhead of sorting the result, you can suppress sorting by specifying ORDER BY NULL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html