# How to optimize this wordpress mysql query?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, query-optimization

Im importing from xml files into a wordpress database. I have towns and locations imported as meta values of each post.

I dont have a predefind list of towns and locations so i need to get all locations (easy thing) and get all towns inside those locations ( im having problems here)

The query i have now is:

```
SELECT t1.meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta t1  
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta t2 ON (t1.post_id = t2.post_id) 
WHERE t2.meta_key = '_prop_loc'
    AND t2.meta_value="Málaga" 
    AND t1.meta_key = '_prop_town' 
GROUP BY t1.meta_value
```

For example if i try to get all towns in "Málaga" location i ended using this query. Testing it on localhost the query runs

```
showing records 0 - 29 ( 101 total, total time 1.3289 seg)
```

If I take out the group by the time decreases but of course I get duplicate rows. If i use select distinct with order ASC the times goes up again.

I do want to have the results ordered, but a query of more than a second is not ok

`wp_postmeta` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta` (
  `meta_id`    bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id`    bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key`   varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY            (`meta_id`),
          KEY `post_id`  (`post_id`),
          KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`)
) ENGINE=***  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Maybe useful: http://www.wikyblog.com/AmanKing/GROUP_BY_in_MySQL_does_implicit_ordering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231907/order-by-null-in-mysql

Comment: But i want the results ordered. Using group by gives me the correct order. Using "select distinc" + order by gives me the correct order. Boths way are slow (queries 1s+

Comment: What indexes do you have on the tables?

Comment: WordPress DB structure:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description I added it to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you haven't added any more indexes on the default WP design.

You can add an index on `(meta_key, meta_value, post_id)`

and one on `(meta_key, post_id, meta_value)`.

**Update**: `meta_value` is a `text` column so this isn't an option. You could try making the first a partial indexes on that column and not including it in the second index:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta 
  ADD INDEX meta_key__meta_value__post_id__IX
    (meta_key, meta_value(20), post_id),
  ADD INDEX meta_key__post_id__IX
    (meta_key, post_id) ;
```

You could also try this rewriting of the query:

```
SELECT t1.meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta t1  
WHERE t1.meta_key = '_prop_town'
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM wp_postmeta t2 
        WHERE t2.meta_key = '_prop_loc'
          AND t2.meta_value = "Málaga" 
          AND t2.post_id = t1.post_id
      ) 
GROUP BY t1.meta_value ;
```

Comment: Adding the indexes did the trick.But my query seems to perform a bit faster. My query is around 0.0415 seg. Your query around 0.0461 seg . Thanks for the great help

Comment: Nice, keep the query that is more efficient. If you remove the `GROUP BY` from my rewriting, do duplicates still appear?