# Mysql MAX and GROUP BY very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

I'm trying to figure our why my query is very slow using MAX, Where and GROUP by.

Table size: 2246096 rows

Indexes:

- created_at_machine_id_idx(created_at,machine_id)

Query:

```
select
     MAX(id) AS id
    ,machine_id
FROM `table`
WHERE `table`.`machine_id` IN (30, 31, 43, 44, 46, 50, 51, 53, 55, 56...)
AND `created_at` <= '2021-11-14 07:45:00'
GROUP BY `machine_id`;
```

Explained:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | table | range | created_at_machine_id_idx | created_at_machine_id_idx | 13 | NULL | 1123048 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |

It takes now between 3 and 4 seconds. I tried more combinations of indexes but without any luck.

Basically I want to get the last id for each machine lower than 2021-11-14 07:45:00.

id is Primary key.

Comment: How many machine_id in the IN?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect this to help it run faster:

```
INDEX(machine_id, created_at, id)
```

Comment: @radu paraleste  Has your performance improved?

Comment: hello all. sorry I was out of the city for few days. Unfortunately no. but I found another stackoverflow question that solved my issue. this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439342/improving-speed-of-sql-query-with-max-where-and-group-by-on-three-different-co . Thank you

Comment: @raduparaleste - That other SO query is not identical to yours.  Please state which index workers best for your query.  Use `EXPLAIN SELECT` to discover it.  And did you use a "self join" like they did?  Also, to use their query, you have to assume that ids are in `created_at` order.  While that may happen to be true, it is not necessarily the case.